# SQL Server Export / Import Sequences

Tags: sql-server, import, export, sequence

What is the best method of exporting SQL Server 2012 `Sequence` objects from one instance to another instance? Is there something similar to the bcp utility that is used for table data?

We have several hundred to transfer. I need to maintain the next value since we are moving table data as well.

Comment: Apologies, it is 2012 - the dangers of writing a post in the evening! Updated the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility would be to have your system create SQL scripts that you can then execute on the other system - something like this:

```
SELECT 
    'CREATE SEQUENCE ' + seq.name + ' AS ' + t.name +
    ' START WITH ' + CAST(seq.current_value AS VARCHAR(20)) + 
    ' INCREMENT BY ' + CAST(seq.increment AS VARCHAR(10))
FROM 
    sys.sequences seq
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON seq.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
```

Running this SQL on a given database produces an output that contains `CREATE SEQUENCE` statement to re-create the sequences, using the `current_value` as the starting point, and using the defined `Increment By` value.

Of course, if you need additional options like `CYCLE` or `NO CYCLE` etc. - everything that's contained in the `sys.sequences` catalog view can be scripted out as needed :-)

Comment: Thanks. I thought that was probably going to be the solution. I guess I was hoping for a more straight forward method, like the bcp utility...